# Model preparation for cavity casting

Tags: modeling, 3d-printing

i am looking for some workflow that could help me with two sided cavity. My problem is that the  model is too complicated for casting into two sided mold that uses just right and left part of the model. If I casted this model it couldn't be taken out of the mold because of the "dead angles"
I tried to detect these dead angles by placing the model between two light, and expected that the area in shadows are in the dead angle and the lights will create a dividing line of the mold.

[image]

This is expected mold and where it will be divided into halfs

[image]

This is my light setup and the areas that needs to bee flatten or filled so the model wont stuck in the mold and it can be opened after the model is casted.

The workflow is not very professional, slow and kind of not exact as the filling and flattening is made by hand.
Is there a way you could advise me to get better, faster or more accurate results to this. Or is it even something that shouldn't be dealt with within blender but using completely different kind of software?

EDIT:

I tried dense plane shrinkwrap from back and front with project shrinkwrap, and actually iam pretty impressed wioth the result. It showed expected dividing line and filled the black areas. Its too much sharp and edgy, but its something.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes ! you need to use shrinkwrap method of curse

- You need to join you dividing plane to your mesh :
  [image]
- then you need to project your surface with desire amount of resolution and apply everything
- then you can select flat (extra faces) by select > linked > linked flat faces and remove remaining dividing faces .
- and choose open edges by double click ( or select all and select > loop > boundary ) and hit "P > selection" then create a volume face behind your mesh(aso add some edges in between to avoid intersection with the mesh itself by selecting two and hit j)
- then use "solidify" modifier on that back temporary face and add a little bit thickness to it then apply everything and join everything together
- then remesh everything and a little smoothing with brush

---

- Bonus tip ! , you can add vertex group after applying shrinkwrap to the mesh and exclude boundary edges (to keep boundary untouched) using vertex group and use Smooth modifier about 10 times ,  and smooth those open edges with smooth brush separately.
  Trust me I've been doin this all the time .
  [image]

Comment: Exactly the workflow I ended up with, and I am pleased with the results. Thanks for breaking this down.

Comment: @Fowl If it's good for you, you can upvote the answer as well as accepting it .. :)